PrimeNg form inputs layout: how to deal with it?
I'm developing an app with Angular 17 and PrimeNg 17, and I'm trying to figure out how to deal with form input alignments.
The "Get started" section of PrimeNg website gives no indication about how to create a form layout.
Even FormLayout section of PrimeFlex website could not help about this, because it shows example of (huge list of) classes for an input without any explanations.
In addition, if I try to use the same classes list with a component (i.e. calendar) instead of a base input it doesn't align like the input text.
With the following code:
<div class="formgrid grid">
    <div class="field col">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input id="firstname" type="text" class="text-base text-color surface-overlay p-2 border-1 border-solid surface-border border-round appearance-none outline-none focus:border-primary w-full">
    </div>
    <div class="field col">
        <label for="monthRange">Month Range</label>
        <p-calendar id="monthRange" [(ngModel)]="date" view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" selectionMode="range"></p-calendar>
    </div>
</div>

As result I get the following layout (it depends on screen size):


As you can see it doesn't align like input text showed in the PrimeFaces example page.
I also tried to search for different way of setting a form layout with PrimeNg, like this old playground (Angular 13 and PrimeNg 13) does, but it seems not to work with latest version of PrimeNg.
Any idea? Any suggestion?

You use PrimeNG so why do you want to use a base input? Delete the classes from <input> and insert the PrimeNG directive for text inputs pInputText. After that it works because all important CSS classes are added through the directive. Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-starter-project-1ukawx?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html

Thank you for your reply. I finally found a solution adding "p-fluid" class -_-

Just added p-fluid class to parent div and it worked (and removed all that shit in the text input class).
<div class="formgrid grid p-fluid">
    <div class="field col">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input id="firstname" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field col">
        <label for="monthRange">Month Range</label>
        <p-calendar id="monthRange" [(ngModel)]="date" view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" selectionMode="range"></p-calendar>
    </div>
</div>

